# Why the amount of input is not increased or decreased?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on the increase or decrease button, the input value with the cartitemCount ID changes dramatically, but does not enter the onchange event, where is my problem, thank you for your help

```
 <div class="qty qty-changer">
    <fieldset>
    <input type="button" value="&#8210;" class="decrease">
    <input id="cartitemCount" onchange="EditCartItem()" type="text"
    class="qty-input" value="@item.Count" data-min="1" data- 
      max="@item.CurrentCount">
    <input type="button" value="+" class="increase">
    </fieldset>
 </div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
function EditCartItem()
    { 
     var cartitemcount=$("#cartitemCount").val();
       $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url: "/CartItem?handler=EditColorToCartItem",
         dataType: "json",
         contentType: "application/json",
         data: {count :cartitemcount} ,
         success: function (data) {
         if (data.isValid) {
           Swal.fire(data.message);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            // do what ever you want to do when error happens
        }
            
        });
    }
```

Comment: There is no code that handle + or - here, you need to detect the click on the buttons and do the increment/decrement

Comment: I can do it on javascript but on jquery I don't have much knowledge

Comment: Where is the javascript code to increase and decrease??

Comment: JavaScript code related to decrease and increase is not a problem, my only problem is that it does not enter the onchange event

Comment: @zeze, `<input type='button'>` [don't have onchange event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)